# Google Ads Tag via GTM shows still running

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-script

lately we're seeing a lot of "still running" Status code in tags that have fired correctly.

The setup is allways the same. We're creating tags via GTM.
The tags fire correctly.
Conversion ID and Label are already doublechecked. ;-)

We can see the error an the following tag types:
Google Ads Remarketing Tags
Google Ads Conversion Tags

Do you have any quick advise?

Comment: Any updates on this ? We are experiencing the same problem. We followed the information on Consent but Consent is known by GTM and is granted..

Answer (score 0):

You can find possible solutions in these atricles:
https://www.analyticsmania.com/post/google-analytics-tag-in-gtm-still-running/
https://www.simoahava.com/analytics/still-running-google-tag-manager-tags/

Comment: Hey Ramon, thanks for you response. We already considered these articles. Nothing is solving our problems.

Answer (score 0):

If you have checked consent mode and everything is fine, please check if your Google Ads ID is a numeric value, if it is add **"AW-"** in front of it and try again. I've had this problem for a client of mine and have been searching for a while on it... This solved the problem , but still pretty odd no information on this change could be found online.

Check my SO question and answer on this :
[GTM - Google Ads Conversion tag Still Running, even when consent is granted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73614260/gtm-google-ads-conversion-tag-still-running-even-when-consent-is-granted)

Comment: Hey Jelman, thank you for your answer. So far it's working and the annoying bug is gone!