# GTM - Google Ads Conversion tag Still Running, even when consent is granted

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-ads-script

Google Conversion Tag on our website keeps in "Still Running" mode. We have been searching the net for a solution and everywhere the Google Consent Mode is given as a possible cause.
Checking in on this, this should not be the problem.. The consent management system sets the default values and also correctly updates the tag when the user changes his settings.

When checking my tag in the Tag Assistant window , I can see that when the tag is fired, the consent is granted (in the consent tab). When I deny consent on ad_storage for testing purposes, the tag isn't triggered at all, which is the way it should be.

So something else must cause this to happen. Any suggestions?

[image: Tag is triggered]
[image: and there is consent..]

Answer (score 2):

Seems that the problem was the Ads ID itself.. It used to work with a numeric value for a year until suddenly the tag got a 400 response. By adding a prefix "AW-" in front of the ID the tag suddenly started working again. Strange behaviour and even stranger I couldn't find anything online about this change..

After trying this the calls didn't come in..
I'm starting to believe that this has something to do with some parts of the website not being GDPR compliant, but Ads should mention this much more clearly.

Comment: We had the EXACT same issue as this one. Consent was good but just out of the blue this started happening. By adding AW- before the tag it started sending data to Google Ads again. Hopefully the data comes in right for you? We're monitoring these changes.

Comment: I got 200 Responses but the data didnt come in (immeadiatly?) so I changed my strategy to Importing GA Events instead of direct Ads calls. Hopefully it works for you , if not and you do find a reason , dont hestitate to add this to this question.

Comment: So, it didn't come in in the end? That's a bummer. What we did at our agency: We transferred all conversion actions to a client's MCC account. This replaces the Conversion ID of the Google Ads conversion. That seems to fix it. However, this is a Google Ads error and we still haven't figured out what's the issue.

Comment: @Jorginton i've changed my answer